# Adding columns to a theme.

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a wordpress site that I have pretty much finished: www.djbliss.com

But the client wants to have 2 post columns in the same style as www.trfonline.com

I have researched the best I know how and have learned that bootstrap might be the best way. But its beyond my knowledge.

Any help or tips with this would be appreciated.

Comment: some WP themes support this. Which theme are you using?

Comment: Its the Sparkling theme from Colorlib. I asked him first in their support forums but he mentioned it would be tricky to accomplish and that it would require bootstrap but that's all the help he could give me.